# How to prevent iOS app from running until the user downloads the newest available version?

Tags: ios

I'm new to Xcode so I'm not sure of all the commands available to me. Is there a specific technique that will allow me to prevent the app from being used if there is a new update available in the App Store and the user has not downloaded it?

I am thinking

[check version of app] -> [check latest version of app in App Store] -> [if not equal, dialog that tells them to download the required update] -> [OK button on dialog sends them to the App Store to download update]

Are any of these possible? I've seen it done in "The Simpsons: Tapped Out" game but I'm not sure how to manage it myself.

If it's really complicated, please just let me know it can be done and point me in the right direction and I'll do my own detective work. I'm not wanting easy answers but I do want to know that I'm not chasing after a dead end.

Comment: If the lookup can't be performed against the App Store, you can have a web service that publishes the newest version of the app. The app would then check this at launch time and proceed as you describe. However, there's no way to handle an offline case. What if a user of your app continued using an older version but never connected to a network? You could also require that the app checks the newest version number via the network every launch, or every week, or so. Can you be more specific about why you want this?

Comment: Professionally developed apps have the latest version (ex 2.0) on a file on a server. When the app boots up, the app compares the version number in the app with the version on the server. If the version on the server is larger than the version on the app, it will display the appropriate message.

Comment: Another issue to think about is if you ever stop supporting an older OS version. So you really need to get the device's OS version and get the newest available software version for that OS version.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092513/how-to-notify-a-user-when-new-updates-version-is-released-on-the-app-store?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You should have a server that is answering requests from your app. In your server-script you replay the last version of your app and possibly what the app should do.

In your app you open an HTTPRequest to this url and handle the reply. The remaining question for your code is what should be done if your server is not reached (e. g. no network connection when starting the app).

Be careful in a userfriendly handling as otherwise Apple might refuse your app.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to put the most up to date version number on a server that you check against.

If the server reports that there is an update, gently let the user know and provide an option to update. If you prevent the user from being able to use the app without the update, you could get into trouble with Apple (and your users).

If you can't access the server, assume you're up to date and do nothing.

When a new version is released on the store, wait 12-24 hours before updating the number on your server as it can sometimes take that long for an app update to propagate to all of the store servers.

Be sure to take into account reasons why the user can't upgrade. Such as is your new version able to run on the users version of the device (iOS 6 when you go iOS 7 only etc). This can be handled by having more information on your server than just the current version number. Perhaps have a plist with compatibility info.

Here's some code you can use to get your version number in the app:

```
NSString* version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
NSString* build = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```